# Automatic OS installation Image?Kickstart?

Tags: centos, kickstart

I have a few HP boxes in the data warehouse that I got the iLO (lights out) level access. 
What I have done:

(1) I just installed CentOS which kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 using virtual media, it is actually most done on the iLO control console GUI by clicking using Mouse.

(2) Also install the "Development Tools" from the installation CD1.

(3) Then I compiled the network driver

(4) I also added the resolve.conf, syscfg-ethx files so I get see the outside network

(5) start the ssh server so the external users can see it.

I am wondering what is the easy way for me to repeat this following the recipe I put in a word document to another boxes?

My thoughts:

(1) Image like AMI from Amazon Web Service... (No clue how to do it)

(2) Some automation scripting solutions form Linux - Kickstart

However, I had a hard time even finding the [kickstart program](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-redhat-config-kickstart.html) in Linux. 
Do I need to install it using RPM or I am not even in the ballpark.

(3) some other magics that the community recommend :)

Thanks a lot for any advice to this entry superuser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to look at a TFTP-server and configure your clients for PXE booting. Then take a look at https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-provisioning-kickstarting.html which is slightly out of date but should get you going.